# Split pandas dataframe column list values to duplicate rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
publication_title    authors                             type ...
title 1              ['author1', 'author2', 'author3']   proceedings
title 2              ['author4', 'author5']              collections
title 3              ['author6', 'author7']              books
.
.
.
```

What I want to do is take the column 'authors' and split the list inside it into several rows by duplicating all the other columns, and I want also to store the results in a new column named: 'author' and keep the original column.

The following depicts exactly what I want to achieve:

```
publication_title    authors                             author          type ...
title 1              ['author1', 'author2', 'author3']   author1         proceedings
title 1              ['author1', 'author2', 'author3']   author2         proceedings
title 1              ['author1', 'author2', 'author3']   author3         proceedings
title 2              ['author4', 'author5']              author4         collections
title 2              ['author4', 'author5']              author5         collections
title 3              ['author6', 'author7']              author6         books
title 3              ['author6', 'author7']              author7         books
.
.
.
```

I have tried to achieve this using pandas DataFrame explode method but I cannot find a way to store the results in a new column.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `pandas 0.25.0` we have the [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) method. First we duplicate the `authors` column and rename it at the same time using [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) then we explode this column to rows and duplicate the other columns:

```
df.assign(author=df['authors']).explode('author')
```

**Output**

```
  publication_title                      authors         type   author
0           title_1  [author1, author2, author3]  proceedings  author1
0           title_1  [author1, author2, author3]  proceedings  author2
0           title_1  [author1, author2, author3]  proceedings  author3
1           title_2           [author4, author5]  collections  author4
1           title_2           [author4, author5]  collections  author5
2           title_3           [author6, author7]        books  author6
2           title_3           [author6, author7]        books  author7
```

---

If you want remove the duplicated index, use [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df.assign(author=df['authors']).explode('author').reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
  publication_title                      authors         type   author
0           title_1  [author1, author2, author3]  proceedings  author1
1           title_1  [author1, author2, author3]  proceedings  author2
2           title_1  [author1, author2, author3]  proceedings  author3
3           title_2           [author4, author5]  collections  author4
4           title_2           [author4, author5]  collections  author5
5           title_3           [author6, author7]        books  author6
6           title_3           [author6, author7]        books  author7
```

Comment: Thanks @Erfan, tour solution is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can first make a new `DataFrame` with the authors:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['author'].tolist(), index=df.index).stack()
```

Next we drop the second level index:

```
df2.index = df2.index.droplevel(1)
```

Next we can concatenate on the second axis:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
     title                       author         type        0
0  title 1  [author1, author2, author3]  proceedings  author1
0  title 1  [author1, author2, author3]  proceedings  author2
0  title 1  [author1, author2, author3]  proceedings  author3
1  title 2           [author4, author5]  collections  author4
1  title 2           [author4, author5]  collections  author5
2  title 3           [author6, author7]        books  author6
2  title 3           [author6, author7]        books  author7
```

or with a one-liner:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df['author'].tolist(), index=df.index).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)], axis=1)
     title                       author         type        0
0  title 1  [author1, author2, author3]  proceedings  author1
0  title 1  [author1, author2, author3]  proceedings  author2
0  title 1  [author1, author2, author3]  proceedings  author3
1  title 2           [author4, author5]  collections  author4
1  title 2           [author4, author5]  collections  author5
2  title 3           [author6, author7]        books  author6
2  title 3           [author6, author7]        books  author7
```

Answer (score 0):

You've discovered `explode` which means you are almost there! Just merge original data with exploded data, see code below,

```
# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'publication_title':['title_1','title_2','title_3'],
              'authors':[['author1', 'author2', 'author3'],['author4', 'author5'],['author6', 'author7']],
              'type':['proceedings','collections','books']})
```

```
(df.explode(column='authors')
   .rename(columns={'authors':'author'})
   .merge(df))
```